# MVC 4 / AJAX - Null values passed to controller despite valid entry from a list

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a "create" form that I am working on. Two of the fields are OriginAirportID and DestinationAirportID.

What currently can be done is someone types in a string of letters in this field, the page then creates an AJAX request using this string to get a set of data back in JSON. This JSON data is then formatted and displayed on the page where a user can click on it and it add's the item name into the field.

Pressing the submit / create button, I have debugged this in Visual Studio and can see that the FromAirport and ToAirport fields are coming up as null.

It is clear that the airport id is not being sent back to the controller and it therefore fails on model validation.

The reason for doing this, instead of a dropdownlist is because loading the page becomes heavy especially with 50,000 airports in the database on two fields (100,000 select items in total).

The HTML mark up for the fields are:

```
        <input type="text" name="OriginAirportID" id="OriginAirportID" />

        <input type="text" name="DestinationAirportID" id="DestinationAirportID" />
```

When someone types in "LHR" in the OriginAirportID field the following is sent:

```
        term=LHR
```

This is the response:

```
        [{"AirportID":16420,"Name":"London Heathrow Airport"}]
```

In my $.ajax is below:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Flight/<MethodName>",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
```

Let me know if this is not clear or confusing and I will try and provide more information.

EDIT: 4/12/14 1844 GMT

Thank you for the three responses so far regarding the model looking like the js object and also the hidden field technique. I shall tinker away with each of the suggestions and see whether it finally accepts the model. StuartLC - I guess I was thinking it was clever but just realised the code you pointed out has no AirportID what so ever! This will definitely compound the problem.

Comment: Surely you need to also keep the `AirportID` returned from the Ajax call  as well, since this is what ultimately gets set in the `OriginAirportID` / `DestinationAirportID` inputs when the form is POSTed e.g.  `return { id: item.AirportID, label: item.Name, value: item.Name };` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're using the actual property from your model as the field for text input by the user, but it looks like those properties are actually supposed to be ints. Once the modelbinder starts processing the posted data, it will attempt to bind the string values to ints, but since something like "LHR" can't be converted to an int, you get a null instead. What you should be doing is something like:

```
<input type="text" id="OriginAirport" />
<input type="hidden" name="OriginAirportID" />
```

The user types in the text box, which isn't bound to anything. Your AJAX use that to lookup the airport id, and then sets the hidden input bound to your actual property with that. Now, when you post, the actual integer id is posted and the modelbinder will be able to bind it to your model properly.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have finally had a chance to try this out and it works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1) Based on user input, you make an AJAX call and get the airport ID and other data. You could save the airport ID in a hidden field or as a "data" attribute of the input field. It makes no big difference, both options will work. Let's assume you work with a hidden field.

2) The same with the destination airport.

Now you have 2 hidden fields, one for the origin and another one for the destination.

3) User submits: in you AJAX call, you create a JS object and set boths IDs (origin ID and destination ID). Something like this:

```
var vm = {};
vm.originAirportId = $("#OriginAirportID").val();
vm.destinationAirportId = $("#DestinationAirportID").val();
```

4) On the ASP.NET MVC Action you should have a ViewModel that has the same properties as the JS object like described below.

```
public class TripVM {
     public int OriginAirportId { get; set; }
     public int DestinationAirportId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, ASP.NET MVC will do the binding for you.

This way you only send to IDs from the client to the server. I recommend you to use JSON.stringify to convert the JS object into a JSON representation.
Remember, the property names of the JS object must match to the properties of the C# class but the comparison is not case sensitive so you can respect each language naming convention :)